# Mouse cursors change when over different handles of an object in ObjectHandles

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I could not find the Mouse cursors change when over different handles of an object in ObjectHandles.
On Mouseover of an objecthandle i need the object holding handle..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/10/changing-the-cursor-in-a-flex-application-using-the-cursormanager-class/

Of course you have to adapt this to your particular case.